# Find the volume rotated around $x$-axis when the area intersect on $x$-axis.

Tags: integration, volume

Given $f(x)=x-1$ and $g(x)=x^2-4x+3$. Let $R$ be area of intersection of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. Find the volume of $R$ rotated around $x$-axis.

First I try to plot the graph of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ as follows.

[image]

Now, I compute the volume of $R$ if rotated around $x$-axis using this formula
$$V=\pi \int\limits_{1}^{4} \left(\left(f(x)\right)^2-\left(g(x)\right)^2\right)dx$$
then I obtained $\dfrac{27}{5}\pi$ unit of volume.

Now I confused that volume is correct or wrong. I confused because $R$ intersect the $x$-axis so if $R$ rotated around $x$-axis then the volume is overlap. So my question:
Does this formula can correctly compute the volume of this problem?
$$V=\pi \int\limits_{1}^{4} \left(\left(f(x)\right)^2-\left(g(x)\right)^2\right)dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should not be used like that. There are parts that **do intersect** and parts that **do not intersect**. For example, let's rotate the functions $f(x)=x^2-1$ and $g(x)=-x^2+1$. If you rotate these two around $x$-axis, you will get the same solid, because $f(x)=-g(x)$. It will have a solid of positive volume, but with your formula, you will get that volume is 0. The problem is that parts of your solid intersect, but **only some parts**. You can try calculating a volume that is bounded by $|g(x)|$, $f(x)$, and $x$-axis (bounded by $|g(x)|$ and $x$-axis on interval $[1,2]$; bounded by $f(x)$ and $|g(x)|$ on interval $[2,4]$). This way, you will not have to worry about the intersection.